# In $SO(3)$, what is the derivative at time $t$ of $R(t) = \exp([\omega]_\times t)$?

Tags: lie-derivative

I cannot wrap my head around something that seems pretty basic.

In ["A micro Lie theory for state estimation in robotics"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.01537.pdf), the authors derive the structure of the Lie algebra of $SO(3)$ by taking the time derivative of the group constraint. Then, assuming a constant angular velocity $\omega$, they conclude that the solution to the ordinary differential equation $\dot{R} = R[\omega]_\times$is the exponential map:

[image: 2]

where $[\omega]_\times$ is a skew-symmetric matrix.

However, if I derive $R(t) = \exp([\omega]_\times t)$ using the [derivative of the exponential map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_of_the_exponential_map), I don't get the same expression:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt} R(t) &= \frac{d}{dt} \exp([\omega]_\times t) = \exp([\omega]_\times t) \; J_r([\omega]_\times t) \; [\omega]_\times \mspace{40mu}
J_r(\tau) \triangleq \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)^k} (ad_\tau)^k \\
&= R(t) \; J_r([\omega]_\times t) \; [\omega]_\times \\
&\neq R(t)\; [\omega]_\times \mspace{40mu} \text{when $t>0$}
\end{align}
$$

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: $R(t)$ is a path in the Lie group, not the Lie algebra; the derivative formula you used is for paths in the Lie algebra.

Comment: Thanks @kobe, though I suspect I'm not getting the nuance correctly. Given $R(t) = \exp(\tau(t))$ such that $R:\mathbb{R} \to SO(3)$ and $\tau:\mathbb{R} \to \mathfrak{so}(3)$, I would expected $\frac{d}{dt} \tau(t)$ to be the derivative of the path Lie algebra, and $\frac{d}{dt} R(t)$ to be the derivative of the path in the group. It is also possible that I am not correctly grasping the domain and image of the derivative
in the Wikipedia article, i.e. that $\frac{d}{dt} \; \exp(X(t)): T\mathfrak{g} \to TG$. Could you elaborate, please?